# How can I get the English spelling of the current default language regardless of the phone language?

Tags: java, android

I need to be able to compare language names between the phone's default language and a a language name that a third party gives me in English.

So if a phone is in Spanish then `"español".equals("spanish")` will fail. So even though the phone is in Spanish, I need the comparison to be `"spanish".equals("spanish")`. Hope that makes sense.

I have found a way to do it but I don't like setting the default `Locale`.

```
Locale def  = Locale.getDefault();
Locale english = Locale.ENGLISH;
Locale.setDefault(english);
```

Now `def` has `Spanish` as the `DisplayLanguage`.

But then I would have to set the default back after I do my comparison. And what happens if at that same time something else queries the locale?

Anyway, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I remember [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) has a map https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py#L1539 that might be useful (IIRC it was obtained from IANA registry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`Locale#getDisplayLanguage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayLanguage(java.util.Locale)) while passing the locale for which you want the name of language translated.

```
String langNameEnUs = 
        Locale
        .getDefault()
        .getDisplayLanguage( Locale.US ) ;  // “Spanish”, not “español” nor “espagnol”.
```

> Spanish

You said:

> But then I would have to set the default back

No, no need to monkey around with the JVM’s current default locale. Simply specify the language you want to use in translating the default locale’s name by passing a `Locale` object.

Here is a demonstration.

```
Locale.setDefault( new Locale( "es" , "ES" ) ) ;  // For the sake of this demonstration, we want to see the language of Spanish, and cultural norms of Spain . 

String langName_en_US = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage( Locale.US ) ; 
String langName_fr_FR = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage( Locale.FRANCE ) ; 
String langName_Japan = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage( Locale.JAPAN ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/0lAOMj).

> Spanish
>
> espagnol
>
> スペイン語

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I did. Have no idea how I missed those getters with a `Locale` argument.